# How to extend testNG?

Tags: java, testng

Junit has runners. they can be used to significantly change the test behavior (like parameterized, spring, zohhak, mockito etc). i know that testNG doesn't have runners, but does it have any way of extending it? any kind of plugins?

Answer (score 1):

Testng has listeners. Refer this link http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners